# how to add another line is javascript

Tags: javascript

how to add another line is javascript?

```
attachments: [{

                    "title": parsedResult.name +" - "+ parsedResult.link,
                    "color": color,
                    "fields": [{
                           "title": pretext + " \n ",
                            "short": "false"
                        },   
                        {
                            "title": "Stock",
                            "value": stock,
                            "short": "false",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": price,
                            "short": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "links",
                            "value": links ('/n'),
                            "short": "false"
                        }
                    ],
```

I have tried `('n')` and `"/n"` but none of them work. The program works but it prints parallel to each other.

Comment: what do you mean by printing, please ?

Comment: also, putting "false" in quotes like that is most likely not what you want

Answer (score 0):

The newline character is always `\n`.
And if you wish to show new line in the html code using javascript I would recommend you to use `<br/>`.

Comment: where do i use that ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML to "print" render the content of your HTML you should consider render a `<br/>` instead of a `\n`. The reasons is that `\n` won't render a line break in HTML.

Example:

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3];
let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
let result = document.getElementById('result');
let html = '';
data.forEach(item => {
  html += `${item}<br/>`;
});
result.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: hello i'm using java script to output in slack

Comment: where do i use <br/>

Comment: @donloyd you should add you <br/> when you create your HTML, I have added an illustrative example.

Comment: @donloyd  ff you found this answer useful please do not forget to accept or upvote this answer using the arrow up or tick on its left side :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what is your output type. If the header says your output is text `\n` is the newline character.

However, in your case I suspect it is not. If you think your output is HTML, use `<br>` instead.

Comment: hello i'm using java script to output in slack

Comment: where do i use <br/>

Comment: replace all the `\n` with `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

The newline character escape is `'\n'`. If you are displaying this with HTML, it will be converted into a space, so you will need to keep the original whitespace formatting with the following CSS: `white-space: pre;`.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is rendered in `<div>`, the text will be auto rendered in new line.

Otherwise, you can add `<br/>` tag in the html also.